# SQL 'between' vs. comparing both ends

Tags: sql

as far as I know, in SQL,

```
X between Y and Z
```

gives the same result as

```
X >= Y and X <= Z
```

But I often see the latter from people I believe to be SQL experts.

Is there a subtle difference that I should know about?

Comment: Those "SQL experts" are no real experts :-) There's absolutely no difference, BETWEEN is just a convenient shortcut.

Comment: If that's true (and I believe it is), then it's more than a convenience--it's a valuable aid to readability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question. In a nutshell, they are essentially the same. Documentation says:

expr BETWEEN min AND max

If expr is greater than or equal to min and expr is less than or equal to max, BETWEEN returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. **This is equivalent to the expression (min <= expr AND expr <= max) if all the arguments are of the same type.** Otherwise type conversion takes place according to the rules described in Section 12.2, “Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation”, but applied to all the three arguments.

reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: Note that type conversion may be a bad thing, if it was inadvertent. I might rather get an error or warning about incorrect types than a bizarre result with false positive matches or something...

Comment: Type conversion that truncates could produce bad results, but it would do so for the other method as well. This is true (as far as I can tell) of all the other warnings at http://www2.sqlblog.com/blogs/john_paul_cook/archive/2013/04/27/problems-using-between.aspx

Comment: Although it isn't worded in an obvious way, this answer implies that the real answer is, "No, there is no subtle difference."

Comment: you're right, added bold and first line to clarify!

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `between` syntax is not ANSI compliant, so it is not implemented in all databases. The most common one `>=` and `<=` can be used everywhere.

Comment: BETWEEN is ANSI compliant.

Comment: Can you name a DB that does not accept 'between' ?  It's such a common word that a web search seems fruitless.  Even putting "between operator" and "ANSI-compliant" in quotes got nothing relevant in the first umpteen hits.  I know it works in SQL Server, MySQL, and SQLite.